# Issue creating new React Native Project: Error running install script for optional dependency: fsevents: Command failed

Tags: node.js, react-native, yarnpkg, node-gyp

I am getting the following: I think it has something to do with python, as I was just fiddling with my python env but can't figure it out:

```
❯ yarn --version
1.16.0
```

```
❯ node --version
v10.15.2
```

```
❯ python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

```
❯ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

```
Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/jordan/Desktop/RnDiffApp/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/jordan/Desktop/RnDiffApp/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.10.0 | darwin | x64
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.10.0/node-v8.10.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.10.0/node-v8.10.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.10.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.10.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2.7
gyp info spawn args [ '/Users/jordan/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jordan/Desktop/RnDiffApp/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jordan/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/8.10.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/8.10.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/jordan/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/jordan/.node-gyp/8.10.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/jordan/Desktop/RnDiffApp/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:53:
In file included from /Users/jordan/.node-gyp/8.10.0/include/node/uv.h:56:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:2:10: error: #include nested too deeply
#include <stddef.h>
         ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <stdint.h>
          ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:72:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <sys/types.h>
          ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:76:10: error: #include nested too deeply
#include <limits.h>
         ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:82:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <inttypes.h>
          ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:53:
In file included from /Users/jordan/.node-gyp/8.10.0/include/node/uv.h:62:
In file included from /Users/jordan/.node-gyp/8.10.0/include/node/uv-unix.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/dirent.h:135:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:110:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:197:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_user_time;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:198:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_system_time;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:199:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:200:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:201:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pageins;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:202:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_wired_size;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:203:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_resident_size;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:204:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_phys_footprint;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:205:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_proc_start_abstime;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:206:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_proc_exit_abstime;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:211:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_user_time;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:212:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_system_time;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:213:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:214:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/jordan/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command \"/Users/jordan/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/node\" \"/Users/jordan/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jordan/Desktop/RnDiffApp/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok"
```

React-native info

```
 React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.2
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8559U CPU @ 2.70GHz
      Memory: 48.09 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 2.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/fish
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.15.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.2/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.2/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.4.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.2/bin/npm
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
        Build Tools: 23.0.1, 26.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
      Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.1 => 16.6.1
      react-native: 0.57.5 => 0.57.5
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Comment: That's the wrong yarn tag.

Comment: @CoryCoolguy You can edit any post to rectify such mistakes. You can also vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to prevent this from happening all the time.

Comment: @leonheess I normally do, but the Stack Overflow editor wouldn't let me save the change because the body of the question was "mostly code." Even though I wasn't changing the body. Thanks for the link to the proposal, I think the change is necessary.